# Pass Username through LoginForm, to GreetingForm, to NavigationForm

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a problem with my database. When I Login the Username into the LoginForm the GreetingForm opens and the LoginForm closes. The username appears on the GreetingForm, but when I click on a button on the GreetingForm which than closes and Open the NavigationForm the username does not appear on the NavigationForm. Can you please help me fix this problem. Click on the link below to see more details.

[Click on this link please](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/pass-username-through-loginform-to-greetingform-to/c8d1f1c2-1b9b-4fc5-b7ef-afa62f811092?auth=1)

Comment: Create a module, add a public variable of data type string, when the user uses the login form set the variable to the user name and now you can access it on all forms.

Comment: @Sorceri   This is what I have in my module

`Public Type UserType
 UserID As Integer
  Username As String
End Type`  

What do you mean by set the variable to the user name. Can you give me example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a `tempvars`. These were introduced in access 2007 and unlike public variables, they will hold their value under the duress of a code error.
`Tempvars` are global , can be created in any module type and are supported in queries.

I would also change the textbox to a combobox. Then you can refer to the column number to select the initials.(column width 0cm)

How to use:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public G_Username As TempVars

Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

  If IsNull(cbo_username) Then
     MsgBox "Please Select User"
  Else
     TempVars!G_Username = Me.cbo_username.column(1)
     DoCmd.Close
     If CurrentProject.AllForms("GreetingForm").IsLoaded = False Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "GreetingForm", acNormal, , , acFormEdit
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

You can now refer to `=G_Username` in any form you require by creating a text box and entering `=G_Username`. Alternatively you should be able to do this in VBA like so:

```
Forms![GreetingForm]![txtLogin] = tempvars!G_Username
```

You can repeat this for `initials`, but refer to whichever column `initials` is in. Remember counting starts from `column(0)`.